# What Samba settings to use for perfect emulation of Windows ACLs

Tags: samba, access-control-list

Can anyone suggest what settings I should use with Samba to get full support for Windows ACLs?

At the moment I have the following configuration:

```
/etc/fstab:    
    acl,user_xattr

/etc/samba/smb.conf:[global]
    inherit acls = yes
    map acl inherit = yes
    vfs objects = acl_xattr
    store dos attributes = yes
    [WinShare]
    comment = Windows Share
    path = /mnt/WinShare
    read only = no
```

Now this is quite close but still doesn't quite give perfect emulation of Windows ACLs, are there any other settings that I should be including to get even closer to making this completely transparent to Windows users?